# NULLs in q and in k.h

Tags: kdb, k

I've found different values for `h` NULLs between `k.h` and `q`:

```
q)0x00 vs 0W
0x7fffffffffffffff
q)0x00 vs 0N
0x8000000000000000
q)0x00 vs 0Ni
0x80000000
q)0x00 vs 0Wi
0x7fffffff
q)0x00 vs 0Wh
0x7fff
q)0x00 vs 0Nh
0x8000
```

In `q` it all looks familiar, but in `k.h` `nh` seems quite strange:

```
// nulls(n?) and infinities(w?)
#define nh ((I)0xFFFF8000)
#define wh ((I)0x7FFF)
#define ni ((I)0x80000000)
#define wi ((I)0x7FFFFFFF)
#define nj ((J)0x8000000000000000LL)
#define wj 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFLL
```

Why is it the `(I)0xFFFF8000` value for `nh`? - Why they didn't just put simply `(H)0x8000`?

Comment: Probably a question better asked on a more official/product channel. Possibly related to the fact that there are various interpretations of NaN/null and infinities in the IEEE standards, e.g. see https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~eedwards/compsys/float/nan.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the extra bits are used to represent the null inside the interpreter or virtual machine, to differentiate it from the short value 0x8000. Using the extra bits to store the non-integer values allows the full use of the 16 bits to represent integers. This avoids having to promote the 0x8000 bit pattern to a 32-bit value, and makes it more efficient to store and process lists of shorts.

When you use `vs` to convert to binary, it looks like it forces 16-bit output, masking off the special bits. However, this isn't the internal binary representation of the special value, which you may be able to see using `0b` as the first parameter. For example:

```
q)0b vs 0W
0111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111b
```

I don't have access to a q prompt to try it for `0Nh` but you can experiment with it.

This is all speculative since I don't have any special knowledge of the q implementation, but I have built several interpreters and VMs and this is what makes sense to me.